# ie8 won't change margin on showing a div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

So, I would love to ignore ie8, but in this case the completed app will be distributed on laptops running only ie8.  I am hoping someone can help as I have run out of knowledge to solve on my own.

For this site, when you click a "tab" on the side of the page, a "tray" appears on the left side of the screen. and the "tab" should move to the right the depth of the "tray".  What I have works well in all webkit browsers, but not ie8.  Here is the code.  Thanks for any input, I am still early in my self education.

button2 is the div holding image2.  thumbnails2 is the "tray"

```
        <script>
    function showThumbnails2() {
        document.getElementById('thumbnails2').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('button2').onclick = hideThumbnails2;
        document.getElementById('image2').style["margin-left"] = "149px";
    }
    function hideThumbnails2() {
        document.getElementById('thumbnails2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('button2').onclick = showThumbnails2;
        document.getElementById('image2').style["margin-left"] = "0px";
    }
    </script>
```

and some more from the body of the doc...

```
    <a onclick="showThumbnails2()" href="#" id="button2"><img src="images/PullButtonleft.png" alt="Click for Topics" width="20" height="100" style="clear:both;display:block; position:absolute; margin-top:334px; left:0px;" id="image2"></a>

    <a onclick="showThumbnails2()" href="#" id="button2"><img src="images/PullButtonleft.png" alt="Click for Topics" width="20" height="100" style="clear:both;display:block; position:absolute; margin-top:334px; left:0px;" id="image2"></a>
```

stackoverflow has been invaluable in helping me get this far, I hope I have asked and formatted this correctly, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the `margin-left` property, why not try using `left: 150px` instead since you are using absolute positioning?  I don't have access to a windows machine so I can't test your `margin-left` issue but changing the `left` property should work.

```
document.getElementById('image2').style.left = "149px";
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  ie8 is going to be the death of me, thank you.